# Factory design pattern in Scala with case classes

Tags: scala, companion-object

I'm trying to implement a factory design pattern in Scala using the apply methods available on the companion object. I have the following approach.

```scala
sealed trait MyType {
  def param: String
}

case class TypeA(param: String) extends MyType
case class TypeB(param: String, anotherParam: String) extends MyType 

object MyType {
  def apply(param: String): TypeA = ???
  def apply(param, anotherParam: String): TypeB = ???
}
```

How do I now force the callers of the above trait to go via the companion object when creating instances of `TypeA` or `TypeB`?

Comment: I want the behavior to be MyType.apply("testParam") should return TypeA. What I want to avoid is users directly calling TypeA("testParam"). So basically what I'm looking at is by-passing the apply method in the case class itself.

Comment: Maybe I miss something, what about finishing the lines like this:

def apply(param: String): TypeA = TypeA(param)
def apply(param: String, anotherParam: String): TypeB = TypeB(param,anotherParam)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can move the case classes inside the companion object, and set the constructors to be private and accessed only within the companion object.

```
sealed trait MyType {
  def param: String
}

object MyType {
  case class TypeA private[MyType] (param: String) extends MyType
  case class TypeB private[MyType] (param: String, anotherParam: String) extends MyType 

  def apply(param: String): TypeA = TypeA(param)
  def apply(param: String, anotherParam: String): TypeB = TypeB(param, anotherParam)
}
```

No one would be able to instantiate the case classes directly, unless though reflection.

```
scala> MyType("Test")
res0: MyType.TypeA = TypeA(Test)

scala> MyType("Test", "another test")
res1: MyType.TypeB = TypeB(Test,another test)

scala> MyType.TypeA("test??")
<console>:12: error: constructor TypeA in class TypeA cannot be accessed in object $iw
              MyType.TypeA("test??")
                     ^
```

Comment: This is what I did after going through some of the articles. Thanks anyways for posting this!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call the `apply` method of the case classes themselves. There doesn't seem to be a way to *prevent* client code from calling `TypeA.apply` directly, though, as that would prevent `MyType` from calling it.

```
sealed trait MyType {
    def param: String
}

case class TypeA(param: String) extends MyType
case class TypeB(param: String, anotherParam: String) extends MyType 

object MyType {
   def apply(param: String): TypeA = TypeA(param)
   def apply(param: String, anotherParam: String): TypeB = TypeB(param, anotherParam)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The trait `MyType` is sealed. That me others can do something like `new MyType{}` to instantiate it.

Then you can remove the case classes.

```scala
// No more public case classes TypeA & TypeB
object MyType {
  def apply(p: String): MyType = /* case A */ new MyType { val param = p }

  private case class InternalB(param: String, other: String) extends MyType
  def apply(param: String, anotherParam: String): MyType = InternalB(param, anotherParam)
}
```

At this point, it's required to use companion object to create `MyType` instances.

Then you can restore pattern matching for these different cases.

```scala
object MyType {
  // the apply functions, plus extractors thereafter...

  /** Extracts mandatory parameter whatever is the case. */
  def unapply(t: MyType): Option[String] = Some(t.param)

  /** Extracts both parameter, extra parameter for case B, None for other */
  def unapply(t: MyType): Option[(String, String)] = t match {
    case InternalB(mandatory, extra)/* Only possible there as private */ =>
      Some(mandatory -> extra)
    case _ => None
  }
}

// Then pattern matching can do...

val test1: Boolean = MyType("A") match {
  case MyType(param) => true
  case _ => false
}
// Will be true

val test2: Boolean = MyType("B", "extraB") match {
  case MyType(param, extra) => true
  case _ => false
}
// Will be true

val test3: Int = MyType("A") match {
  case MyType(param, extra) => 2
  case MyType(param) => 1
  case _ => 0 
}
// Will be 1

val test4: Boolean = MyType("B", "extraB") match {
  case MyType(param) => true
  case _ => false
}
// Will be true
```

It allows a full control over instantiation, and abstraction over implementation of cases.